# Crystal Reports MVVM Data Source

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, crystal-reports-xi

I have an MVVM application and would like to add Crystal Reports. I have a ViewModel of PatientList and would Like to Bind the Report to an Observable collection of Patients in the ViewModel. the Collection is not appearing in the data sources window.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are refering to Crystal-Reports datasource window right?
If so - I think you will never find the ObservableCollection there (and I don't know if you can have CR observe the collection) but on the document-class in Crystal-Report you should have something like `SetDatasource` (I don't have the newest version anymore and CR changed this from time to time) - in the last version I know you had to cast to `IEnumerable<...>` in some cases (`DataTable`) so look out for this too.